# Classify handwritten digits from images using Caffe

Tags: c++, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to use a trained LeNet model from mnist example to classify a digit from a given image. I am following the [cpp classification example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/9a244f9bcf/examples/cpp_classification) as it reads an image(ImageNet data though) and classifies it. 
I am confused about what the sysnet file in Imagenet is and how it is used for classification? Also do we need a label file for Lenet to classify handwritten digits and if so, how to create one and how should the format be?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial on this topic by caffe itself here: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html. They will explain this better than I ever could.

However for labelling there are multiple ways to do this. Most commonly the images are just split up per folder. Then the 1 folder contains images that show the number 1, the folder 2 shows images with the number 2 and so on. Then you can exploit that to load in the training data.

However you could also create a label file for every image and write the corresponding number into the label file. Then you just need to know the name schema to find the label file.

Comment: I was having a doubt as to how to classify. In the link to the cpp_classification(given in question), they have used synset_words.txt which is a label file and whose format I don't understand. Could you be more specific as to the format of the label file, is it just simply a number?

Comment: This label file has nothing to do with digit recognition. It has to do with object detection on imagenet. It is a mapping from id to object class as can be seen here: http://image-net.org/download-API

Comment: I'm not able to understand how that is used in classify images in Imagenet though. Then what all files would I actually require for classification of digits then? I need the prototxt file which defines the netwrok, the .caffemodel with all the weights and the image right? Is the mean_image file required or is it only used during training?

Comment: The prototxt file also defines the input file. The input file in case of http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html is examples/mnist/mnist_train_lmdb. This file includes both the image data and the labels. A description of what files are possible can be found here: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2042.

Comment: Classification is done using a model that outputs some class for a specific image. A class is just a number. Now we want to know the name of that class. Therefore we supply a label file that maps the classes to the corresponding object. That is the synset_words.txt file.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for clearing the confusion about sysnets :). So now I'm confused how to classify the images(number) using the cpp_classification example(link given in example). They are using a mean image file but isn't that only required during training and not testing?